# PowerBi Dax - Create a Measure that ignores applied filters and display in barchart

Tags: powerbi, dax, power-bi-report-server

In my data I have two columns of date - claim registration date and resolved date. My report is using resolved date as a slicer filter. I would like to build a bar chart showing registered claims by client segments. I have tried several approaches and functions but they all return single count value. What I want is actual counted values for each type.

```
BySegmentRegistered = CALCULATE(COUNT(claims_data[client_id]),claims_data[reg_date].[MonthNo] == MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE(DateTable[MonthYear])),ALL(claims_data))

BySegmentRegistered = CALCULATE(COUNT(claims_data[client_id]),FILTER(ALL(claims_data),claims_data[reg_date].[MonthNo] == MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE(DateTable[MonthYear]))))
```

I have tried above code and several other iterations but they all return single value across all client_segments. If I simply do `COUNT(claims_data[client_id])` than it displays count by each segment but date is wrong, hence it doesnt work for me.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I just tried this and it works.

```
BySegmentRegistered = CALCULATE(COUNT(claims_data[cliend_id]), claims_data[reg_date].[MonthNo] == MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE(DateTable[MonthYear])), REMOVEFILTERS(DateTable[MonthYear]))
```

Comment: Hi, Did you check `MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE(DateTable[MonthYear]))`? Also you can try, ALL(), instead of ALL(claims_data) , but put SELECTEDVALUE(DateTable[MonthYear]) into a variable before Calculate(). ALL() removes all filters from the data model. ALL(claims_data) removes only direct filter, if you have some crossfilters they will not be removed

Comment: better to add your graph screenshot, and columns and tables names that are involved